# Перезвон с телефона по условию

Tags: python, android, linux

Дано: Есть шлагбаум у которого в базе для открытия есть один телефонный номер. Если позвонить на этот номер, шлагбаум откроется.

Переадресация, как вы понимаете, не подходит, потому что нужно, чтобы звонок был именно с того номера, который добавлен в шлагбаум.

Задача: Нужно сделать так, чтобы, когда звонишь на номер, который добавлен в этот шлагбаум, аппарат сам звонил на шлагбаум.

Конкретно что делать описывать не нужно - нужна идея реализации данной задачи.

Варианты с Asterisk не очень хочется рассматривать, так как никогда не сталкивался с этой технологией. Хотелось бы как-то через скрипт на Python, запущенный на зарученном смартфоне с андроидом.

Comment: Как вариант звонить через SIP провайдера, например mango-office.

Answer (score 0):

Я таким баловался давно, ещё до появления смартфонов. Поэтому могу подсказать только ключевые слова

- gsm-модем
- AT-команды

Я это делал через скрипт, который работал компьютере и управлял кнопочным телефоном подклеченым к компьютеру. Вместо телефона к компьютеру может быть подключен gsm-модем (донгл).